# Username in tab configuration context is empty

Tags: microsoft-teams

I cannot seem to be able to find the current user's username using the Microsoft Teams JS library. I am always given an empty value.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WyVb.png) are the properties of the variable `context` in

```
window.microsoftTeams.getContext(function(context){
    // my stuff
}
```

`channelId`, `isFullScreen`, `locale`, `teamId`, `theme` are provided, and once I finish configuring my tab and I try to edit it, so is the `entityId` I provided.
However, the `upn` property is always empty.

Is it caused by the fact that I'm side-loading my package or is it caused by something else ?
Did anyone manage to get an user's username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the documentation is partly outdated. In my manifest `needsIdentity` was set to `true` in my manifest but it didn't have any effect.
I searched in the [schema reference](https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json) for the manifest and found out about the `permissions` array, in which you can put `identity` and `messageTeamMembers`.

After adding that to my manifest, the `upn` is correctly provided in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your manifest to see if you've set needsIdentity. From the [MSDN Context page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/jslibrary#Context). Please validate that this answered your question! Thanks.

upn?: string
The current user's upn. As a malicious party can host content in a malicious browser, this value should only be used as a hint as to who the user is and never as proof of identity. **This field is only available when needsIdentity is set in the manifest.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to find the solution !